# read from console with RISC-V assembler

Tags: linux, assembly, riscv

I`m new to assembler and try to write simlpe program, that:

1. Prints prompt to enter string
2. Reads string from console
3. Prints entered string to console

Here is the code of the program:

```
.section .text
.globl _start
_start:

    .equ stdin, 0
    .equ stdout, 1


# Print prompt msg
    li a0, stdout           # print to stdout
lbl1:
    auipc a1, %pcrel_hi(msg)    # load msg(hi)
    addi a1, a1, %pcrel_lo(lbl1)    # load msg(lo)   

    li a2, 13           # length of the message
    li a3, 0
    li a7, 64           # _NR_sys_write
    ecall               # system call


# Read string from termial
    li a0, stdin            # read from stdin
    li a1, 0
lbl2:
    auipc a1, %pcrel_hi(abuf)   # load msg(hi)
    addi a1, a1, %pcrel_lo(lbl2)    # load msg(lo)
    li a2, 5            # size of string to read
    li a3, 0
    li a7, 63           # _NR_sys_read
    ecall               # system call   

# Print readen string
    li a0, stdout
    li a1, 0
lbl3:
    auipc a1, %pcrel_hi(abuf)   # load msg(hi)
    addi a1, a1, %pcrel_lo(lbl3)    # load msg(lo)
    li a2, 32           # size of string to print
    li a3, 0
    li a7, 64           # _NR_sys_write
    ecall               # system call

    li a0, 0
    li a1, 0
    li a2, 0
    li a3, 0
    li a7, 93           # _NR_sys_exit
    ecall               # system call

.section .rodata
msg:   
    .string "Enter string\n"

abuf:
    .word buf
buf:
    .zero 32
```

I can compile the programm. While running I get the prompt message in the console,
BUT when I input a test data, for example "dog", kind of junk is printed to the console.

Target platform:
*Linux Ubuntu-riscv64 5.11.12 #1 SMP Fri Apr 9 10:39:01 -03 2021 riscv64 riscv64 riscv64 GNU/Linux*

Here is also ouput of *strace* command

```
# strace ./a.out 
execve("./a.out", ["./a.out"], 0x3ffffd6570 /* 23 vars */) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x2ab05c8000
faccessat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x3fc2084000
mprotect(0x2ab05c5000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE|PROT_EXEC) = 0
mprotect(0x2ab05c5000, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC) = 0
mprotect(0x2ab05c6000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
write(1, "Enter string\n", 13Enter string
)          = 13
read(0, dog
0x2ab05c52e6, 5)                = -1 EFAULT (Bad address)
write(1, "\352R\\\260*\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0", 32�R\�*) = 32
exit(0)                                 = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Can anybody say what I`m doing wrong?

Comment: As you can see, your `read` already faults because you pass a bad address. Putting a buffer into a read-only section is not likely to be successful :) Also it's unclear why you are using `abuf`.

Comment: Thanks, Jester! I put the RW buffer into `.data` section instead of `.rodata` and the program get worked!
What about `abuf` - it is the address of the `buf` that I pass to the syscall. Is the any better way to do that?

Comment: You shouldn't need the `abuf`, just use `buf`. The way I see it, you are not loading the pointer, you are passing `&abuf` to the syscall.

Comment: Just to clarify. When using `abuf` we pass pointer to pointer to the syscall. But what is the root cause of that behavior? When the memory for the buffer is reserved though `.zero` direcrive, lablel `buff` already contains the address of the reserved buffer?

Comment: The syscall does **not** expect a pointer to pointer which is why you should not use `abuf`. Labels are already addresses, yes. Using a pointer to pointer makes sense if you can't address pc-relative. In that case you need to actually load the pointer, which you did not do.